# selenium problem error 500 in the server and NoSuchElementException in the code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a URL lists (297 urls) and I'm trying to scrap a table named "
Tableau des niveaux d'eau par classe" in each url to put it into a big dataframe. I use selenium because I had to click on an element to bring up the table.

The code is working but there is an error NoSuchElementException that block me. I don't know why but sometimes the website gives an "Error 500", which means that my code can no longer find the right elements in the html code, because the page changes. Do you know where the problem could come from? And how to fix it?

Here's my code :

```
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

opts = FirefoxOptions()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()

result=[]
timeout = 10

with open("path of the file") as in_file:
    for url in in_file: 
            #ouverture de la page
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
            driver.get(url)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            print(driver.current_url)

            time.sleep(10)

            #click on the button
            button =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/div[2]/h2[3]/a")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

            time.sleep(10)

            # scrap every column of the table
            try:
                table = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[8]"))
                WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(table)
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
            name= driver.find_elements(By.ID, "codeComplet")
            classe= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[1]")
            janv= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[2]")
            fev= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[3]")
            mars= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[4]")
            avril= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[5]")
            mai= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[6]")
            juin= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[7]")
            juillet= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[8]")
            aout= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[9]")
            septembre= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[10]")
            octobre= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[11]")
            novembre= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[12]")
            decembre= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MesureGraphTabPeriode']/tbody/tr/td[13]")
            
            name = name * len(septembre)
            

            for i in range(len(janv)):
                temporary_data= {"Nom": name[i].text,
                                "Classe": classe[i].text,
                                "Janvier": janv[i].text,
                                "Fevrier": fev[i].text,
                                "Mars": mars[i].text,
                                "Avril": avril[i].text,
                                "Mai": mai[i].text,
                                "Juin": juin[i].text,
                                "Juillet": juillet[i].text,
                                "Aout": aout[i].text,
                                "Septembre": septembre[i].text,
                                "Octobre": octobre[i].text,
                                "Novembre": novembre[i].text,
                                "Decembre": decembre[i].text
                                }
                result.append(temporary_data)

    driver.close() 

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Here's a sample of my urls file :

```
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00067X0183/PZ1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00104X0054/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00115X0011/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00147D0218/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00148D0177/F2#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00241X0012/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00254X0037/PZ1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00271X0002/P2#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00291X0031/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00332X0007/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00365X0003/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00367X0026/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00387X0184/PZCC1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00444X0008/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00471X0010/H1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00471X0095/PZ2013#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00497X0018/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00516X0059/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00578X0043/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00633X0132/FR.PAC#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00634X0039/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00675X0019/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00692X0062/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00732X0032/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00775X0099/F14#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00777X0008/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00805X0002/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00836X0007/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00845X0036/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00853X0018/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00853X0030/PZ2013#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00941X0034/S-2#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00956X0055/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00987X0009/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01013X0004/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01024X0058/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01046X0010/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01074X0006/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01086X0011/LS4#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01102X0025/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01116X0138/F1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01192X0043/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01198X0002/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01205X0229/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01205X0541/P7#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01245X0010/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01252X0011/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01258X0020/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01264X0029/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01266X1013/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01287X0017/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01293X0071/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01308X0082/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01377X0205/F3#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01381X0070/P25#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01423X0044/F4#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01446X0005/S3-91#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01473X0087/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01487X0001/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01516X0004/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01522X0069/PZ2008#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01543X0028/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01548X0010/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01584X0023/LV3#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01616X0006/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01794X0035/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01805X0036/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01825X0091/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01868X0030/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01871X0031/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01891X0047/PZ1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01907X0043/FR3#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01907X0068/PZ2013#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=01937X0054/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02144X0005/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02163X0015/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02206X0022/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02255X0003/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02267X0030/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02276X0050/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02347X0022/314#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02408X0016/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02473X0037/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02478X0156/PZ#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02523X0002/S2#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02542X0035/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02558X0034/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02566X0019/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02603X0009/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02605X0062/M4#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02606X0112/G5#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02617X0009/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02636X0009/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02648X0020/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02663X0001/S#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02726X0029/238#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02796X0044/PZ#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02903X0029/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02927X1013/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02936X2005/PFAEP#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02943X0013/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02961X1003/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=02982X0028/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03027X0007/F1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03081X0025/223#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03107X0008/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03124X0088/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03128X0011/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03228X0048/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03237X0021/PZ16#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03263X0004/FAEP#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03287X0018/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03302X1012/S1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03314X1035/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03387X0040/S#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03427X0027/92#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03577X0012/PZ13#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03593X0055/PZ#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03612X0098/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03622X0027/PZ#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03626X0026/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03634X0093/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03662X0222/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03693X0017/P2#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03717X0020/PZ#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03754X0015/F2#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03783X0046/71#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03871X0016/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03927X0055/PZ#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03936X0056/PZ#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03953X0028/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=03958X0002/PF#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04051X0016/SONDAG#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04103X0022/FC#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04137X0018/15#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04202X0013/S9#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04285X0016/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04333X0011/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04447X0028/S#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04518X0042/PZ8#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04563X0105/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04604X0001/FAEP#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04623X0053/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04644X0002/PUITS#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04702X0019/SONDAG#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04934X0043/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04936X0010/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=04994X0229/S#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05007X0014/S#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05076X0019/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05092X0009/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05155X0002/FAEP#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05162X0008/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05203X0083/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05208X0011/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05271X0017/SONDAG#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05285X0374/P7#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05464X0045/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05471X0070/P1#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05472X0029/P#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05553X0009/S2#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05573X0084/F.6#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05625X0036/F#mesures_stats_4
https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=05664X0048/P#mesures_stats_4
```